# Access the column DisplayName from within a custom field's CreateChildControls()

Tags: 2010, development, custom-field-types

I am making a custom field in SharePoint 2010.  From within the `CreateChildControls()` function, I would like to refer to the field by the name it has been given in the list.  Is this possible?

For instance, if I have an ISBN field based on [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861799.aspx), how can I tell that this column in a list has a DisplayName of "ISBN", while in another list (or even that same list!) there is another ISBN field named "Old ISBN"?

Answer (score 2):

You normally should not access data in `CreateChildControls()` because the control itself may not be in a completed state yet.  Referencing data should happen in the `Load()` event as the [control lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719775%28vs.71%29.aspx) shows.  More detailed info is [available here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms178472.aspx).

Assuming your custom field is based on one of the basic SharePoint controls, you should be able to access the display name of the field simply with `this.Title`.

Comment: In the example, a default value is set in CreateChildControls. I want to manipulate the default value as well... Should I move this default value code into OnLoad()?

Comment: You may want to set the default value in CreateChildControls to some known bad value like "$DEFAULTVALUE&" and then change it in Load() when you have all of the control data available.  The known bad value lets you easily determine if you are dealing with the actual default value or a loaded value.

Comment: where does CreateChildControls() fall in the whole page lifecycle?  I can't find it listed in either of those links...

Comment: It is called when needed, that is, usually prior `PreRender()` on a GET and prior to `Load()` on a postback.  You can include a call to `EnsureChildControls()` at the start of your `Load()` to make sure everything is in place prior to working with the data.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use `this.FieldName` to access the static name of the field.  I would prefer to use the display name, but the static name will have to do for now.